# How do i format a sql numeric type with commas on Sybase SQLAnywhere?

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere

I came across the following solution but it does not work on Sybase

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(987654321 AS money), 1)
```

I have read the [Convert](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc36271_1251/html/blocks/X41864.htm) Sybase information but still i receive the same number without the commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried giving a varchar (20) for example instead ? something like :

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), CAST(987654321 AS money), 1)
```

In SqlAnywhere money datatype is a domain, implemented as NUMERIC(19,4).

in CAST function , If you do not indicate a length for character string types, the database server chooses an appropriate length. If neither precision nor scale is specified for a DECIMAL conversion, the database server selects appropriate values.

So maybe this is what's causing the issue, what do you get as output ? do you get `987654321.00` , or just `987654321` ?

Update:

My last suggestion would be using `insertstr()` function and loop through the char value of your number to insert comma every 3 digits .. this is not the cleanest/easiest way but apparently SQLAnywhere deal with money datatype as normal NUMERIC datatype ...

`insertstr()` documentation is [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/insertstr-function.html).

I would give you a code sample but I don't have SQLAnywhere installed to test it ...

Comment: I tried with varchar(20) but i still get 987654321.0000 as result.

Comment: In SQL Anywhere, VARCHAR without length defaults to VARCHAR(30) when it is the target of a CONVERT() or CAST(). It has nothing to do with the comma formatting.

Comment: I ended up creating an SP that uses the insertstr() function to insert the comma character every 3 digits as you suggested, that seems to be the easiest way to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is the SP i created based on F Karam suggestion.
CREATE FUNCTION "DBA"."formattednumber"( in @number numeric) 
returns char(60)
begin
  declare @returnnumber char(60);
  declare @workingnumber char(60);
  declare @n_ind char(1);
  declare @decimalnumber char(10);
  declare @tempnumber char(60);
  declare @decimalpos integer;
  if isnull(@number,'') = '' then
    return null
  end if;
  if @number < 0 then set @n_ind = 'Y'
  else set @n_ind = 'N'
  end if;
  set @workingnumber = convert(char(60),ABS(@number));
  set @decimalpos = patindex('%.%',@workingnumber);
  if @decimalpos > 0 then
      set @decimalnumber = substr(@workingnumber,@decimalpos);
      set @decimalnumber = "left"(@decimalnumber,3+1);
      set @workingnumber = "left"(@workingnumber,@decimalpos-1)
    end if end if;
  set @returnnumber = '';

  while length(@workingnumber) > 3 loop

    set @tempnumber = "right"(@workingnumber,3);
    set @returnnumber = insertstr(0,@returnnumber,@tempnumber);
    set @workingnumber = "left"(@workingnumber,length(@workingnumber)-3);
    if length(@workingnumber) > 0 then
      set @returnnumber = insertstr(0,@returnnumber,',')
    end if
  end loop; 
  if length(@workingnumber) > 0 then
    set @returnnumber = insertstr(0,@returnnumber,@workingnumber)
  end if;

  if length(@decimalnumber) > 0 then
    set @returnnumber = @returnnumber+@decimalnumber
  end if;

  if @n_ind = 'Y' then set @returnnumber = '-' || @returnnumber
  end if;
  return(@returnnumber)
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between server-side and client-side formatting. When you use the 'isql' client for example (the TDS client), then the result will be this:

```
1> select convert(money, 9876543210)
2> go
 9876543210
 ------------------------
         9,876,543,210.00

(1 row affected)
```

But this is purely because the client application happens to format 'money' values this way. Also, this is actually not specific for SQLA, since isql is originally the client tool for ASE (a different Sybase database).

When you run the same conversion at the SQLA server (i.e. as part of an expression in a SQL statement), those commas will not be there since SQLA doesn't have such a built-in formatting style. 
If you want this, you should write a SQL function that formats the number as you desire.